# Native driver find from Mongoose model not returning Cursor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to execute a native MongoDB `find` query via the `collection` property of a Mongoose `Model`.  I'm not supplying a callback so I expect the find to return a `Cursor` object, but it returns `undefined` instead.  According to the [Mongoose docs](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose), the driver being used is accessible via `YourModel.collection` and if I switch to purely using the native driver code `find` does return a `Cursor` so I can't figure out what's going on.

Here's a code snippet that reproduces the problem:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'test');
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    emailAddress: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

var cursor = User.collection.find({});
// cursor will be set to undefined
```

I've tried to step into the code with node-inspector, but it's not letting me.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The native driver methods are all proxied to run on the nextTick so return values from the driver are not returned.

Instead, you can pass a callback and the 2nd arg returned is the cursor.

```
User.collection.find({}, function (err, cursor) {
  // 
});
```

Curious why you need to bypass mongoose?

Comment: Ah, well that explains it.  Thanks, Aaron.  The motivation for doing it was just some experimentation during performance testing.  And when it didn't work as I expected I couldn't seem to let it go until I understood what was going on.

Comment: For anyone finding this and not sure what to do with it, bypassing mongoose like this and using the native driver will return a cursor, which you then need to turn into an array if you want to use it (such as res.json(doc) or what have you)...

    User.collection.find({}, function (err, cursor) {
        cursor.toArray(function(err,doc) {
          // do stuff with doc
        });  
    });