# Mongoose and native mongodb driver api 2.1 issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to access the native mongodb driver and as far as I can see mongoose is using mongodb version 2.1 which means the 2.1 api should be available.

From reading mongoose I hear until the mongoose object has connected to the database it buffers all of the operations. When it has connected to the database it proceeds to carry out those operations, so this shouldn't have anything to do with querying the database before the connection is made.

```
co(function* () {
    var Model = schema.getModel();

    Model.collection.findOne({}, function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc); // <--- displays
    });

    var doc = yield Model.collection.find({}).limit(1); // <--- throws error
    console.log(doc); // <--- does not display
});
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find

Comment: Likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588808/native-driver-find-from-mongoose-model-not-returning-cursor

Comment: @JohnnyHK Haha wow! Quick and correct, I'm impressed.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Have you filed an issue on github about this? The documentation on mongoose says you can access the native driver and with thus said it should work as expected, however it doesn't.

Comment: No, the Mongoose author was the one that provided the answer and it sounded like this is working as designed. Filing an issue against the docs would probably make sense though. Go for it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ah cool that the author answered. Will do! :)

Comment: FWIW, it's not freezing, it's throwing an error that you don't catch :)

Comment: @robertklep Ah, true! I forget that I must catch them in co!