# Mongoose driver methods not returning promises

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

using `mongoose@4.4.20` `bluebird@3.4.1` `mongodb@3.0.20` `node@4.4.7`

Per mongoose docs, I've specified the promise library like this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect('db_uri', {promiseLibrary: Promise});
```

However, driver methods return `undefined` when Promise is expected per the node mongodb driver docs and source.

```
MyModel.collection.insertOne(doc); //undefined
MyModel.collection.updateMany(criteria, update); //undefined
MyModel.collection.find(criteria); //not even a cursor, undefined
//...and so on
```

Another question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591802/6562901) that explains the behavior but it relies on callback.

How do I use driver methods with promises without manually promisify-ing them like this `MyModel.collection.method(...).then(...).catch(...)`?

Comment: Try directly mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird'); and the same on the connect.

Maybe the word Promise is reserved.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa tried it. didn't work.

Comment: Im using 'q' and works fine